# How to block confidential information with Launch Screen or Image in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

How can I hide confidential information inside my app, by blocking the view with the launch image when app moved to background? I am creating the application using Swift and iOS 11.

Below is something others have used in the App Delegate on older versions of Swift, but I cannot figure out why if does on work on the current version:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];

    imageView.tag = 101;    // Give some decent tagvalue or keep a reference of imageView in self
//    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];   // assuming Default.png is your splash image's name

    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your code is in Objective-c not swift , you can try this in swift

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    let im = UIImageView()

    im.tag = 12

    im.frame = (self.window?.frame)!

    im.image = UIImage.init(named: "add.png")

    application.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(im)               
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let sub = application.keyWindow?.subviews.last
    {
        for vv in sub.subviews
        {
            if(vv.tag == 12)
            {
                vv.removeFromSuperview()
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible for xcode to select which image to use based on the iPhones model? (smaller image for smaller phone...etc.)

Comment: @Daniel use you can put 1x,2x,3x for an image in **Assests.xcassests**

Answer (score 1):

> I have updated the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` with the following code and it worked:

**In `applicationDidEnterBackground`:**

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: self.window!.bounds)
    imageView.tag = 101
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Default.png")
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

**In `applicationWillEnterForeground`:**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let subviews = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.subviews {
        for view in subviews {
            if view.tag == 101 {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```